# How can I use numpy to change an array's shape to be in columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array:

```
[
  [[1],[2],[3]], 
  [[1],[2],[3]]
] # I don't know how many [[1],[2],[3]] there will be (the batch size)
```

I want it to become

```
[
  [[1], [1]],
  [[2], [2]],
  [[3], [3]]
]
```

Doing the following `reshape` in numpy yields an incorrect result:

```
np.reshape(x, (3, -1, 1))

[
  [[1], [2]]
  [[3], [1]]
  [[2], [3]]
]
```

How can I utilise numpy to correctly reformat/reshape the array?

Comment: `x.T` ? might do what you want

Comment: That inner most size 1 dimension complicates the display without adding (much) generality.  `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` would be as good an example. (a (2,3) vs (2,3,1)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `x.transpose([1, 0, 2])`

`np.reshape` reshapes the dimensions without changing the order of the data. `np.transpose` allows you to change the order of specified dimensions. In this example, you are swapping dimensions 1 and 0 while leaving dimension 2 in place.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([
  [[1],[2],[3]],
  [[1],[2],[3]]
])

expected = np.array([
  [[1], [1]],
  [[2], [2]],
  [[3], [3]]
])

assert np.all(x.transpose([1, 0, 2]) == expected)
```

Comment: Nice. This works but I think it should be x.transpose([1, 0, -1]) instead of x.transpose([1, 0, 2]) so that it can handle any batch size.

Comment: @DylanKerler. The array has three dimensions, regardless of how big the dimensions are. Both formulations are exactly equivalent.

Comment: This should work for any batch size, but not for any number of dimensions. As @MadPhysicist said, the formulations are equivalent. you could do something like `[1, 0, *list(range(2, x.ndim))]` to extend this to any number of dimensions.

Comment: Ah right makes sense. I just assumed (incorrectly) what the "2" was doing.